# Test in (IE8 and previous) on Mac without using Parallels?

Tags: macos, internet-explorer

Can can anyone tell me if there is a reliable way to test(or simulate) in IE version 8 and previous when on a Mac? (without installing Parallels)
Perhaps some sort of web application or tool?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I test my web pages in Microsoft Internet Explorer on a Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55577/how-can-i-test-my-web-pages-in-microsoft-internet-explorer-on-a-mac) and tons of others. Do a search.

Comment: ok, came across one method using Virtual Box http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/04/internet-explorer-for-mac-ie7-ie8-ie-9-free/

Answer (score 0):

Old question but might still be useful to someone... I discover that it is possible to test through the develop menu on safari. 
Go to develop > user agent and then choose IE8

Solution found here http://www.imore.com/how-view-websites-your-mac-require-internet-explorer-or-pc