# Testing website with VirtualBox + IE8 on OS X specific urls not resolving

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, virtualbox

I'm using [this](http://www.xairon.net/2011/06/testing-ie6-7-8-and-9-on-mac-os-x/) method, which was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55577/how-can-i-test-my-web-pages-in-microsoft-internet-explorer-on-a-mac) to test IE on a development server through OS X.

URLs such as foobar.com resolve, but if I try to go to my development server such as dev-8.foobar.com:3000, it won't resolve.

I even tried changing the hosts file, but that didn't do anything worthwhile. Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Please add the steps you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't remember exactly how I did it, but the key is to get the IP address that the Windows VM uses to access the host Mac system. I found this by opening up command line utility (Start > Run > "cmd" > ) and typing the command "ipconfig". I think that's what it was. Not sure and don't have time to check now. You should be able to figure out the IP to use Windows' hosts file from there.

Next time I'll try to be even more vague...

Comment: Glad that worked. If you don't mind, please add the steps you used to get that and which IP address it was so that others can have something less vague than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find your ip address by going to mac's system preferences, and clicking on the network settings. Select your method of internet connection and the text on the right will tell you your IP.