# Can't access localhost from OSX VirtualBox Windows 8.1 IE11

Tags: windows, macos, internet-explorer, virtualbox, modern.ie

I have consulted some references already:

- [Running ie on your mac free](http://mozmonkey.com/2013/09/running-ie-on-your-mac-for-free-via-modern-ie/)
- [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261975/addressing-localhost-from-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine)
- [And this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55577/how-can-i-test-my-web-pages-in-microsoft-internet-explorer-on-a-mac)

I am using OSX 10.10.5 and VirtualBox 5.0.16. I am trying to debug some web apps on IE11 using the free virtual machine that Microsoft provides from [this site](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/mac/). I am using the Win 8.1 and IE11 image.

My understanding is that I should be able to just make an adjustment to the VM's hosts file and then I can access localhost through `10.0.2.2` However, that has not been the case.

I have tried various entries:

- `10.0.2.2 localhost`
- `10.0.2.2 outer`
- `10.0.2.2 subdomain.localhost` - one thread suggested trying this

I have also tried changing the network setting for the image in VirtualBox. I have tried both NAT and Bridged with no success...

No matter what I put in the address bar of IE, it tells me the page can't be displayed. I have tried:

- `http://localhost`
- `http://localhost:80`
- `http://localhost:8888`
- `http://outer`
- `http://10.0.2.2`
- `http://10.0.2.2:3000`
- `http://10.0.2.2:80`

No combination of addresses/hosts file config seems to do the trick. One thread suggested trying `ping 10.0.0.2` on the command line in the VM. I tried it and it appears to respond; the output says that 4 packets were sent and received.

I'm very frustrated at this point, and uncertain how to proceed. It also tried this with the Win7 IE11 VM image and didn't have any luck. The other threads on SO seem to suggest that I can just visit `10.0.2.2` with the way the VM is configured out of the box. If anybody has any suggestions, or could point me in the right direction, it would be really helpful!

Comment: I am also struggling with this. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: https://medium.com/@urubuz/accessing-localhost-in-mac-from-windows-vm-in-virtualbox-312a3de6fedb - fixed it for me though looks like you tried that combo